# Repeated hits on my site from different IP addresses trying to access .aspx files using all my bandwidth

Tags: web-crawlers, ip-address, 403-forbidden, aspx

I checked my raw access files after being notified that my site has been limited over the last 24 hours and see different IP addresses trying to access files with .aspx extensions, see attached log image.

What are they trying to do and how can they be coming in every millisecond or so from different IP addresses?

[image: snapshot of raw access logs]

I thought I'd update my question because this continues to happen and for the first time a request with no IP Address - see third log entry

[image: NO IP Address on POST]

Comment: These look like hack attempts from several already compromised systems trying to replicate a payload. I assume you are using a Microsoft computer since the response code is 403. It is possible the response code is encouraging the hack. Make sure your software, all of it, is up to date. Not knowing Microsoft products any more, I cannot advise you. However, if your software is up to date and your system continues to return a 403, then you should be safe from these attacks.

Comment: I'm not using a Microsoft computer and this has nothing to do with my computer.  The screenshot is an excerpt from Raw Access Logs from one of the sites on a shared server account.  None of my sites are ASP sites and I have 403 redirects set up on all of the sites for forbidden sections of the sites in htaccess, so the server is right to return 403's.  My question is about the different IP addresses, how could this be coming from so many IP addresses and what are they trying to do?

Comment: as closetnoc said, they are hacking attempts. I get them hundreds of times a day on my server. Its normal.

Comment: @mike Ok so they are hacking attempts, but what about the IP addresses ?

Comment: While I appreciate a good ole 403, you may be encouraging the attack. It is far better to return a 404. I am very aware of what this is. I studied attack signatures for over a decade. You can block these IP addresses in your firewall if you have one. I run two with an IP gap. I recommend them when possible.

Comment: *...but what about the IP addresses...* What about them? These are compromised computers on the net. As the attack advances, you can see more. Ignore them or block them. You cannot stop the attacks.

Comment: this will help: go to: https://www.whois.com/whois/xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx and replace xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx to learn about the origins and details of each IP address. I bet many will come from china.

Comment: @Mike Only hundreds? I got 93k on July 4 alone! You must be doing something right. Of course I baited hackers for years... maybe that has something to do with it. Cheers!!

Comment: I got to the point where I disabled logging for repeated useless requests to speed up the server

Comment: Boy I'm really confused now, I set up the 403's to block access to certain directories within each site.  I just checked Mike's whois link and the first IP I checked had a range of XXX.XXX.0.0 to XXX.XXX.255.255 that's a hell of a lot of IP's coming in from the US - do you have any good pointers on where I can conduct 403 vs 404 implementation?

Comment: You can leave the 403s you set up. You are okay. It is just that a 403 is a positive response where a 404 is a negative response. You can safely ignore these attacks. They will eventually go away. No harm no foul. Cheers!!

Comment: Those don't look like hacking attempts to me.   Those look like they may be requests for a site that used to be on your domain name.  Hacking probes tend to try to access admin areas.

Comment: Looks like there's less than one request per second. It it's just returning an empty 403/404 page, it shouldn't have any significant effect on performance or bandwidth, even on a slow server. If it does, you probably have something poorly designed, like loading a whole framework and creating database connections just to display error page.

Comment: @StephenOstermiller Or vulnerabilities in ASP and .dlls. This is a typical profile. I am looking into this for detail but so far what I see is not entirely clear.

Comment: @StephenOstermiller just to clarify the sites are not, nor ever have been ASP sites, the 403's are in place to protect admin areas

Comment: @zod It's not really possible to specifically answer what they are trying to do and how they can do it, but as you can see from the community's responses, you're returning a `403` on URLs that you say don't exist (since you don't use ASP). This only indicates that they're _forbidden_, which is a green-light for bots and hackers. You should just return a `404` or `410` for all requests ending in `.aspx`. You can go a step further and automatically add any IP that requests `show.aspx` or `ogShow.aspx`to the IP tables in your firewall so they're banned - how to do so depends on your environment.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're either under attack ([DDoS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Denial-of-service_attack)) or you're very popular and this is legitimate traffic (however, considering '403' the last is unlikely). And yes, if you've received this IP only recently then the requests are legitimate traffic to the previous owner of your IP.

There are quite a few ways to protect, and the most effective of them is a third-party CDN with such option. To name a few: CloudFlare, MaxCDN, Anazon CloudFront. Even without DDoS-protection CDN should be effective because it should cache '403' Unsure but it can have better effect if you respond with 404 instead of 403.

Comment: all our sites are already going through Cloudflare, I'll check the logs again today and see if it is still continuing

Comment: you are right my provider is under a DDoS attack and it is continuing